# How to make a message pop up based on a date user selected?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

So I am doing a reminder tool in Visual Basic for myself and I added a MonthCalendar to the windows (check image). It runs great. User writes down the name and a date (in 24 hour format for now) and then when you click the add reminder, it registers it into the listbox and also writes it into a file so when user closes and opens the application, it stays there. When the time in my PC coincides with the one in the program, a message pops up. The only thing left I'm having trouble is with dates.

I want to be able to choose a date and a message popping at that day with the time. I know it might be simple, but for some reason I can't think of a way and searching around didn't help me.

Here's a snippet of the code I have for when the time coincides:

```
If (TimeValue(Now) = time) Then 'Dim time As String = l.Substring(0, 9)
                MsgBox(msg) 
            End If
```

I thought using an If statement similar to this would work, but it tells me that dates really don't go well with boolean and I tried looking around the subfunctions, but I've yet to find any.

To be clear: The only thing I need is to be able to register the date. Here's an image of the designer view.

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QASK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Timer`.  Calculate how many milliseconds there are until the event and set the `Interval` of the `Timer` to that value.  The maximum `Interval` value gives you just over 24 days.  If you need more than that then simply set the `Interval` again when the `Tick` occurs.  You keep going in jumps of ~24 days until you get to the event.

Comment: seems like a viable choice, but would it work as well if I chose a date to be reminded for on the calendar control? (I added the design view to get an idea of what I am going for)

Comment: Whether you use the `MonthCalendar` is irrelevant.  The calculation to determine the time until the event will be subtracting the current `DateTime` from a `DateTime` for the event to get a `TimeSpan`.  Where the `DateTime` comes from has no bearing on how it gets used.